# Web API Lowercase Route

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

Hy there,

I need to enforce Lowercase routes in my Web API project.
If it was an MVC project i would use something like

```
routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
```

But in Web API that property does not exists.

I tried the [LowercaseRoutesMVC4](http://lowercaseroutesmvc.codeplex.com/) NuGet extension but my routes needs to have a custom handler so that extension does not help me.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you try this one with route constraints already ? https://gist.github.com/benfoster/3274578

Answer (score 7):

This looks like it does what you need

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { url = new LowercaseRouteConstraint() }
        );
    }
}

public class LowercaseRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var path = httpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        return path.Equals(path.ToLowerInvariant(), StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

I found this at https://gist.github.com/benfoster/3274578#file-gistfile1-cs-L4

Answer (score -2):

I have json config like

```
public class JsonConfig
{
    public static void Initiliaze(HttpConfiguration config, bool isCamelCase)
    {
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
        json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.None;

        if (isCamelCase)
            json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
}
```

You can call this method in WebApiConfig.cs like

```
JsonConfig.Initiliaze(config, true);
```